# Why doesn't videocapture.read() work in opencvsharp4?

Tags: c#, opencv

i used opencvsharp4 in c#.

First, I used the webcam on my laptop using VideoCapture.FromCamera(0);

```
capture = VideoCapture.FromCamera(0);
if (capture.IsOpened())
{
    if (capture.Read(frame))
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame))
        {
            image = bmp;
            pictureBox1.Source = BitmapToImageSource(image);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine.

But after changing to VideoCapture.FromCamera(1), when the usb camera is connected and operated, the return value of capture.Read(frame) becomes false.

Why is that? Is this a camera issue?

Comment: You are sure `1` is the right index?

Comment: yes, opencv recognizes 0,1. 0 is the webcam and 1 is the usbcamera.  For reference, the model name of my camera is ELP-USBFHD08S-MFV.

Comment: If the camera is already used by another app then you can't acces it. Only one app can access camera at a time.